# Tiny Tower progress lost

Tags: tiny-tower

I was playing Tiny Tower, and had 28 floors, 33 costumes left, and about 20,000 coins. But then when I came back later, all of my progress was lost somehow.

I have tried deleting and reinstalling, but that didn’t work.
I have tried backing up from different emails and that hasn’t worked.

I’m logged into Game Centre but that still hasn’t worked, although it says that it’s still there on the same Game Centre account.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Please don't rollback to versions of your post that has obvious mistakes. If you don't agree with some edits, by all means change them, but this is a community website, and I make edits to improve posts for everyone. If you don't like that, you're on the wrong website.